# Installing PostGIS after PostgreSQL Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, postgis-2.0

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.5
```

returns a series of errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.5 : 
  Depends: libgdal1i (>= 1.9.0) but it is not installable
  Depends: libjson-c2 (>= 0.11) but it is not installable
  Depends: liblwgeom-2.5-0 (>= 2.5.0~beta1) but it is not going to be installed
  Depends: libproj9 (>= 4.9.0) but it is not installable
  Depends: libsfcgal1 (>= 1.2.0) but it is not installable
```

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I had never encountered a `not installable` exception to date so I ma not sure of consequences of different possible actions... Attempting lower versions leads to the same result.  How can PostGIS get safely installed then?

**Update**

An attempt was also made, making a fresh installation of a Ubuntu 18.04 VM [following these instructions][1]

The source of the error was in adding the repository to sources.list

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt xenial-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
```

which should be for 18.04

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
```

*[to butter things up even more, and attempt was made with  `bioni-pgdg main`  leading to its own set of errors]!*

Comment: These instructions usually work for me on ubuntu/linux mint: https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS24UbuntuPGSQL10Apt

Comment: I'd seen a posting of yours similarly beforehand & used as an indicator.  Tried anew and same errors.

Comment: I'll have to do another test...

Comment: did another few tests and found the hiccup

Comment: glad the instructions still work!!

Comment: "sudo apt-get install postgis" doesn't work?

Comment: @TurboGraphxBeige  not in this instance (if my memory serves me correctly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Unmet Dependencies

The [UbuntuGIS Quickstart Guide](https://trac.osgeo.org/ubuntugis/wiki/QuickStartGuide) lists a few things that need to be done before installing their packages (these packages include PostGIS).

The first is that your `/etc/apt/sources.list` must include the "universe" and "multiverse" repositories. Edit that file to add them. There should already be a line that lists "main". In the end, it will look like this:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main  
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main  
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main  

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main universe multiverse  
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main universe multiverse  
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main universe multiverse
```

This is where all of your dependencies come from.

### Install Repository

After that, you need to install the [UbuntuGIS repository](https://trac.osgeo.org/ubuntugis/wiki/UbuntuGISRepository)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
```

Once this is done, you should be able to install postgis in the typical way:

```
sudo apt install postgis
```

Note: there will be a lot of items to install.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the **proper** repository is added to the sources.list

```
sudo lsb_release -a
```

ensure the codename is the same in the add repository command:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt **Codename**-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
```